# Qt 4.8 changes in QWidget?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qt4.8

I have a certain `QWidget` derived class.

Look at the window flags i'm giving it. In my app it functions like the drop down component of the combo box:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Popup);
```

With Qt 4.7.4, the "FocusOutEvent" is called when I click outside of the widget, even if the click is on the window caption. I use the event to hide my widget. That's the desired behavior I'd like to see. With 4.8 however, "FocusOutEvent" is never called when clicking outside my widget on non-focus receiving elements and/or my window caption, thus, it still sticks around. I can actually drag the window away from my still-visible popup widget.

Something changed in Qt 4.8. Is there a way around it?

Comment: None of the conventional techniques work here. No mouse grabbing, no eventFilter. Qt doesn’t get any event when i click my OSX window caption. I show my popup, grab my OSX window caption, and drag the window away from the still opened popup. For me, this is a new deal-breaker bug introduced in Qt 4.8. Qt 4.7.4 works well, the popup disappears as soon as I click the window caption. Reluctantly I am forced to revert to 4.7.4. Pity.

Comment: Submitted https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-24162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround, suggested by Volker, a major Qt Contributor: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/14264